# 画面の特定領域においてのみマルチタッチできるようにしたい

Tags: java, android

※Qiita/teratailにも同じ質問を投稿しております。

#### 実現したいこと

JavaでAndroidスマホアプリを作っております。
画面の特定領域（最下段に示したyellowArea）においてのみ、
マルチタッチできる、コードの記述方法をご教示ください。

#### 試したこと

下記ソースコードにて、マルチタッチ（Ｔ１→Ｔ２･･･）してみました。
その結果、Ｔ１は、yellowAreaのみ受け付けてくれますが、
それ以降のタッチ（Ｔ２・・・）は、yellowArea以外の領域でも
受け付けられてしまいます。Ｔ２以降も、yellowAreaのみ受け付けて
くれるように、検討を進めておりますが、
なかなか解決に至らず。質問させて頂いた次第です。方向性だけでも
ご教示頂ければ幸いです。

#### ソースコード

```
//MainActivityの基本コードは省略します。
yellowArea.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //マルチタッチのループ
        int count = event.getPointerCount();
        for (int j=0; j<count; j++) {
            int eventAction = event.getActionMasked();
            int pid = event.getPointerId(j);
            int id = event.findPointerIndex(pid);

            switch (eventAction) {
                //最初のタッチ（T1）
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //処理内容は省略
                break;
                //追加タッチ（T2以降）
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    //処理内容は省略
                break;
                //その他のアクションは省略
            }
            //処理内容は省略
        } //マルチタップのループ
        return true;
    } //boolean onTouch
}); //リスナー
```

#### スマホ画面（横置きの例）

[image: スマホ画面（横置きの例）]

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/pjf0ivqa47nwuw) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
の処理内で、追加タッチ座標がyellowArea外の場合は
受け付けないようにする処理が必要だったようです。

参考サイト：
https://www.javatips.net/api/android.view.view.ontouchlistener
Example 83, Example 93

追伸：曖昧な質問で申し訳ありませんでした。